# Apple Mail.app columns to be displayed

Tags: mac, email

How do I display in Mac's Mail.app the senders' name?

It only displays the email. I don't see any choice under Preferences.

Answer (score 1):

Switch on 'Use Smart Addresses' in prefs > Viewing.
<sub>Pic from Mojave, same pref exists in Big Sur</sub>

[image]